# S22.Imap not working with .msg (Outlook mail item) files which are added as attachments

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, imap

I'm using s22.Imap to fetch emails from the server along with their attachments. I'm able to write all the attachments using the below code except the .msg file attachments.

It's a ASP.NET Core 2.1 / C# application in which the below code is inside a mail utility class.

```
foreach (Attachment attachment in message.Attachments)
{
    byte[] allBytes = new byte[attachment.ContentStream.Length];
    int bytesRead = attachment.ContentStream.Read(allBytes, 0, (int)attachment.ContentStream.Length);
    string destinationFile = @"C:\\Path\\" + attachment.Name;
    BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(destinationFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None));
    writer.Write(allBytes);
    writer.Close();
}
```

Everytime S22.Imap returns a different file name and extension like 'dqcbws10.pnx'. Is there any specific way to deal with .msg files returned by S22.IMAP.

The C# code in my post is able to handle all other attachment formats like .xls, .xlsx, .zip, .dat. But when a .msg file like SampleMessage.msg is retrieved through S22.IMAP library it gets converted into somthing like "dqcbws10.pnx" instead of SampleMessage.msg. What needs to be done to get it converted into "SampleMessage.msg". Googling it came up with suggestions like it's of the format rfc822. I need pointers on how to convert "dqcbws10.pnx" into "SampleMessage.msg".

Comment: You can handle them any way you want. What is the question here? Are you asking why the sender hasn't suggested a file name? The sender doesn't have to name attachments.

Comment: Hi arnt, thanks for your time. I've edited my post to add more information.

Comment: Maybe I see... there is no actual conversion going on, merely a choice of filename. You can rename the file.